# update current location on mapview but locatinListenor is in service

Tags: android, locationlistener

i have mapActivity where i register my MapView widget and i m running service that checks location data  in background. i m starting my service in mapactivity through BroadcastReceiver like this

```
  public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    private MapView view;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.themap);
    view.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    Intent in = new Intent();
    MyReceiver locationRecvr = new MyReceiver();
    locationRecvr.onReceive(getApplicationContext(), in);

  }
 ......................

 }
```

**myReveiver.java**

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "MyReceiver Started..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       Log.v("Debug", "MyReceiver Started..");
       Intent myIntent=new Intent(context, ServiceLocation.class);        
       context.startService(myIntent);
}
 }
```

and myservice and LocationListener like this

```
  public class ServiceLocation extends Service implements LocationListener {
       ......
       ..... 
       .... 
  }
```

my question is when location is changed how can i change that location on mapview how can i get mapview reference in onLocationchanged() methods or how can i send latitude and longitude to mapActivity.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

send broadcast when user location is updated in your location listener.
and update location in maps.
In broadcasted intent you can also pass updated location.

Comment: Thankx for ur reply. can u explain how can i send and then receive in mapactivity plz.....

Comment: Try implementing broadcast reciever.
look for braodcast recicever
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Answer (score 0):

From your service , You can send send Lat/Longs to the MapActivity.
You can start the MapActivity from there by putting lap/longs in Intent Extra.

In your MapActivity --

```
 /**
 * Setting Google Map to provided location 
 */

 private void setMaptoProvidedLocation() {
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 LAT = intent.getIntExtra(DisplayActivity.LAT, DisplayActivity.DEF_LAT);
 LNG = intent.getIntExtra(DisplayActivity.LNG, DisplayActivity.DEF_LNG);

 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 mapView.setSatellite(true);
 mapController = mapView.getController();


 mapController.setZoom(ZOOM_LEVEL - ZOOM_LEVEL / 2);
 GeoPoint vehicleLocation = new GeoPoint(LAT, LNG);
 mapController.animateTo(vehicleLocation);
 // You can also add map overlays ...

}

//If MapDisplayActivity is in forground and we want to update the new location

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
super.onNewIntent(intent);
setIntent(intent);
Log.d("MapActivity","Got new Data again");
setMaptoProvidedLocation(false);
}
```

Comment: please tell me where i have to write these function, in mapActivity or in my service class that implements LocationListener?????

Comment: You have to write above two functions in your MapActivity . Whenever your service gets new update from LocationListener , It would send the latest lat/longs to the MapActivity .

Answer (score 0):

We need to use locationManager and LocationUpdates as

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
```

we can set the parameter as required which reprsents distance and time.
and later we should define a function as

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
}
```

for further information [click here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html)